# Show Array of Name in foreach loop in Card Header

Tags: laravel

Good Afternoon.
I am new to coding and working on home web application.
Currently stuck on situation where I am showing the cards (using foreach ) based on no's of society  name( get from database ) in the page.
I am getting the total Nos. of card as per nos of society received from database. Now want to show Society name in card header.

Here is my controoler where i get the society name.

```
$getsocietyname = DB::table('Customer')->select(DB::raw('society'))->groupBy('society') 
                  ->get(); // get society name
```

Ref attached image showing the output.

Blade file where i need to show Society name in card header.

```
<div class="row">

                                                            @foreach ($getsocietyname as $item )

                                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">

                                                                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                                        <div class="card-header">
                                                                            <strong>{{ $getsocietyname }} </strong>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                                                            <li class="list-group-item">Total Customer</li>
                                                                            <li class="list-group-item">Active Customer</li>
                                                                        </ul>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                </div>

                                                            @endforeach

                                                        </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're printing `$getsocietyname` while you should be printing `$item`.

Since you're using a for each, the `$item` var contains the information of a single society.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can u guide me more about how to add $item in foreach loop. Sorry but i am self leaner from YouTube video so not much aware how to do the same. Thanks again

Comment: Currently you've `<strong>{{ $getsocietyname }} </strong>` which echos the value of `$getsocietyname` which is the array. you've to replace that line with `<strong>{{ $item }} </strong>`. Since `$item` is created in the foreach loop, and contains the information of a single society